# Best Practice to Update Spring Repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have Spring Repo class which look like this :

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository
        extends CrudRepository<Employee, Long> {


    @Query("Select s from Employee s where s.Id = ?1")
    Optional<Employee> findEmployeeByID(String Id);


     @Transactional
     @Modifying 
     @Query(" How to DO that")
     UpdateEmployeeDetails()


}
```

How to efficiently update the Employee details, as employee tables contains more than 15 fields i can't write a function for each of these fields, how we can generate a query which will have common logic to update

For Example :
If we want to update name only so `UpdateEmployeeDetails()` will execute this query :

```
UPDATE Employee SET firstName=UPPER(firstName) WHERE id in :ids
```

If we want to update name and address :

```
UPDATE Employee SET firstName=UPPER(firstName), Address = "Address" WHERE id in :ids
```

How we can do this efficiently  as there are may fields so we want to generate query dynamically

Comment: If you're using JPA then just load the employee and change the data on the entity within the same transaction. JPA should then detect the changes and update the database accordingly - at the end of the transaction at the latest. Otherwise you could also just pass the changed entity and let JPA merge it or just update everything (changing a column from "A" to "A" shouldn't hurt).

Comment: Remove those additional methods and just call `findById` and `save` (or when already attached to a session you don't need to even call save). JPA does all that for you already. If you only want to update the fields that changed you can annotate your entity with `@DynamicUpdate`, else you will get an `UPDATE` query with all the fields. I strongly suggest you read up on how JPA works and also what Spring Data JPA provides. Finally please remove the `@Repository` from those interfaces, that isn't needed (and hurts my eyes ;) ).